# pass some value in the url to the parent window from child window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a main window, I will use the window.open to open a child window. Now I want to pass some value as parameter to the URL of the parent window from the child window and refresh the parent window. How can I do this??

Comment: what is your aim? you can send Query string while opening window. `window.open("http://www.yousite.com?param=x")`

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this:

```
window.open("http://www.yousite.com","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
```

these are the parameters you can use:

status - The status bar at the bottom of the window.
toolbar -   The standard browser toolbar, with buttons such as Back and Forward.
location -  The Location entry field where you enter the URL.
menubar -   The menu bar of the window
directories -   The standard browser directory buttons, such as What’s New and What’s Cool
resizable - Allow/Disallow the user to resize the window.
scrollbars -    Enable the scrollbars if the document is bigger than the window
height -    Specifies the height of the window in pixels. (example: height=’350′)
width - Specifies the width of the window in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

```
function openpopup(url)
{        window.open(url,'pop_window','toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,height=300,
width=450,left=200,top=200');

}


 //call from code behind 

  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "aa", "<script language="'javascript'">openpopup('page1.aspx?variable="+variabledata+"');</script>");
```